# Why won't Blender paint the picked color?

Tags: uv-image-editor

When I pick a color in the Image Editor, and then proceed to paint with the picked color, the paint does not match the color I picked..

[image]

Why does the painted color not match the color I picked?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: could you please pack your image and share your file (only the image, remove the rest)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It appears from the picture that you have not a single color, as I see darker shades of this color near the "outlet holes".   The color picker will pick the color from a single pixel.   Have you tried other nearby areas to pick from?